# Bash Scripting - Ping Monitoring?

Tags: apache, bash, unix, scripting, redhat

I've created a batch file in Windows which pings all servers in the network in regular time intervals and displays the server status on a web page whether the server is online/offline and the uptime of the server.

How can I do this in redhat and put it onto an apache web server but I have no idea where to start with the bash script? Any guidance or code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everything what you done in windows-batch file is doable with bash too. (and much more). Therefore, try step-by-step convert the windows-batch to the bash script. Divide it to logical parts, and ask an _exact_ question. In this form, I can say only: learn bash and some utilities.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach that will give you insights about the state of your servers would be by using network monitoring tools such as [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). Both of these have different approaches to network monitoring, but they're both great with a relatively low learning curve. Once you set up these tools, any authorized user can get details about your servers, network, and even add scripts to send emails/texts in case of anomalies/servers going down.

Here is a tutorial for setting up with [Nagios](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Tutorials/Nagios-Core-Tutorials) and with [Munin](http://waste.mandragor.org/munin_tutorial/munin.html).

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a linux terminal, I would recommend a tool named nmap to get a list of all the devices in your network.

```
[root@puppet Desktop]# nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-06-17 17:20 IST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1
Host is up (0.0025s latency).
MAC Address: C4:E9:84:B8:D9:B6 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for puppet (192.168.0.50)
Host is up.
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.51
Host is up.
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.52
Host is up.
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.106
Host is up (0.00042s latency).
MAC Address: B4:6D:83:B1:C0:47 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.200
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (6 hosts up) scanned in 9.67 seconds
```

You can put this in a bash script and set up a cron job so that it runs in regular intervals of time and gives you the output in a text file or a file that is read by your Webserver (Apache, nginx etc.)

I would also recommend using an application named Nagios through which you can monitor all the devices in your network as well. The initial setup will be a little cumbersome but later on it is all sorted. Please note that using Nagios, you can monitor services for nodes running Linux as well as Windows OS. You can use the inbuilt checks for eg. Ping, Http, IMAP, POP, SMTP, SSH or make your own custom checks.

You may find the following URL helpful for installation: https://www.tecmint.com/install-nagios-in-linux/

Regards,

Rohan Dsouza